# MVC programming practices

Tags: model-view-controller, qt, architecture, modularity

I'm working on some new software, and I'm trying to make it as modular as possible. I have been coding for a while..but I lack some key principles which I am learning as I go along.

In trying to make my current project modular, I am using the model-view-controller architecture. In designing my application, I have found certain things I am unsure of. So I come to you...

I'll give you some information which may be useful:

- I am developing this application in Qt.
- It is a desktop application.
- Single user, so it is not very complicated

My questions are:

1. When implementing the various modules(models, views etc..) and all
   of the classes associated with them, should I be initializing
   modules within modules? Should I create a 'model' instance within a
   'controller', or should I create everything in 'MAIN' and simply
   pass the modules as references?
2. My strategy is to separate my application into many MVC bundles.
   Each one will follow the basic principles: model gets the data, view
   displays it, and controller takes care of all interactions between
   model-view, and performs all required logic. Is this correct?

I appreciate all of your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I create a 'model' instance within a 'controller', or should I create everything in 'MAIN' and simply pass the modules as references?

Pass the modules as references.  I don't know if Qt has the concept of packages within a bundle, but in Java, I have separate packages for the model and the view.

> My strategy is to separate my application into many MVC bundles. Each one will follow the basic principles: model gets the data, view displays it, and controller takes care of all interactions between model-view, and performs all required logic. Is this correct?

Yes, that's correct MVC principles.

Sometimes in a more complicated application, your application view might consist of the GUI (a view) and a model of the GUI (a model).  In this case, the application model, which is probably a database access model, interacts with the GUI model.  The controller for both the GUI and the application is driven by the actions of the user.